# How to access jetty server from webapp?

Tags: java, jetty, jetty-9

I would like to edit Connectors on the fly on my web-app code. However, for achieving this, I need to access the server from the web-app. How can do this access? It was tried going up from the JMX but it did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

At my case, using JMX was the solution. I looked at the MBeans and I found out Beans directly related to what I wanted, I iterated over the beans and performed my actions over the right ones. This way,  I could start/stop them and get the effect I wanted to.

Comment: Could you please add some detail to your answer to help future visitors?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, @JasonMArcher, I added a bit more information.